# GetxController structure

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

```
class Controller extends GetxController {
  int currentIdx = ''.obs;
  void updateInt(int idx) {
    currentIdx = idx.obs;
  }
}
```

here is my controller. Now I put this line a widget to get idx value and assign immediately to currentIdx value:

```
Controller().updateInt(idx);
```

but .obs lines gives error in this current structure.

when I change the controller:

```
class Controller extends GetxController {
  RxInt currentIdx = 0.obs;
  void updateInt(RxInt idx) {
    currentIdx = idx;
  }
}
```

this time Controller().updateInt(idx); gives error. (RxInt not compatible int value)

how can I handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare and use like that:

```
RxInt currentIdx = 0.obs;
void updateInt(int id) {
    currentIdx.value = id;
  }
```

Comment: `Obx(() => Text(Controller().currentIdx.toString())),` gives always 0 result.

Comment: If you use `Controller()` always create a new instance. Declare first `Controller controller = new Controller()` and then set value to `controller.currentIdx`. In widgets you must call `controller.currentIdx.value.toString()`